# A function given as an integral is uniformly continuous provided the integrand is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-continuity, integral-inequality

I need to show that this inequality holds:

> $| \int_{0}^{1} (h \nabla f(x+sh-y) -h \nabla f(x-y)) ds | \leq |h| \varepsilon(|h|)$

For a function $\varepsilon$ which verifies $\varepsilon (|h|) \to 0  $ as $|h| \to 0$, where $f \in C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|h|<1$.

This is supposed to be obtained from the fact that $\nabla f$ is uniformly continuous on $ \mathbb{R}^n$.

I don't know how to proceed, I know that if a continuous function f is compactly supported, then it is uniformly continuous. As $f \in C_{c}^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$,  $\nabla f$ is also compactly suported and continuous, so it is also uniformly continuous.

But I don't know how to pass it to the given integral.

**Edit:**

Following Andrew D. Hwang's clue, we have:

$| \int_{0}^{1} (h \nabla f(x+sh-y) -h \nabla f(x-y)) ds | \leq  \int_{0}^{1} |(h \nabla f(x+sh-y) -h \nabla f(x-y))| ds \leq \int_{0}^{1} |(h \nabla f(x+sh-y)| +|h \nabla f(x-y))| ds$.

Here, as the first part of the integral is equal to $ f(x+h-y)-f(x-y)$, and f is uniformly continuous, we have that for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists $\varepsilon_1$ such that $\varepsilon_1(|h|) \to 0$ as $|h| \to 0$ so that this inequality holds:

$$\int_{0}^{1} |(h \nabla f(x+sh-y)| \leq \varepsilon_1(|h|) $$

And argue the same way for the second part of the integral, which verifies $\int_{0}^{1}|-h \nabla f(x-y)|ds=|-h \nabla f(x-y)|$, obtaining $\varepsilon_2$.

Then $\varepsilon= \varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2$. Is this correct?

**Note**: This inequality is needed in the book *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, by Haim Brezis*, in the proof of the proposition 4.20.

Comment: The triangle inequality for integrals should help get you started. :)

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Thanks for the tip, I have edited my answer with the proof, to be checked.

Comment: If you are interested in the so-called _modulus of continuity_, see exercise 1.17 in this [pdf](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/grads/clungstr/real_analysis/hwset1.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon(h)= \sup_{|z-w|\le |h|}|\nabla f(z) - \nabla f(w)|.$ By the uniform continuity of $\nabla f,$ $\lim_{h\to 0} \epsilon(h) = 0.$ We then have

$$| \int_{0}^{1} (h \nabla f(x+sh-y) -h \nabla f(x-y))\, ds | \le  \int_{0}^{1} |h |\,|\nabla f(x+sh-y) -\nabla f(x-y)| \,ds$$ $$ \le  \int_{0}^{1} |h |\,\epsilon(h) \,ds = |h |\,\epsilon(h)$$

as desired.